# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: javascript, xml, cors, access-control

tengo una problema con CORS y no se como resolverlo.

"No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access."

Mi código es el siguiente:

```js
window.onload = function() {
 var mb = document.getElementById("myBtn");
 mb.addEventListener("click", clickSomethingMatch);
}
function clickSomethingMatch() {

 var createCORSRequest = function(method, url) {
   var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
   if ("withCredentials" in xhr) {
     // Most browsers.
     xhr.open(method, url, true);
   } else if (typeof XDomainRequest != "undefined") {
     // IE8 & IE9
     xhr = new XDomainRequest();
     xhr.open(method, url);
   } else {
     // CORS not supported.
     xhr = null;
   }
   return xhr;
 };

 var url = 'https://euw1.api.riotgames.com/lol/summoner/v3/summoners/by-name/NAMEXXX?api_key=APIKEYXXX';
 var method = 'GET';
 var xhr = createCORSRequest(method, url);
 xhr.send();

 xhr.onerror = function() {
  alert('Woops, hay un error con el request');
 }
 xhr.onreadystatechange =  function(a) {
   if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
   var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
  }
  document.getElementById("span").innerText = response;
 };
}
```

Comment: Normalmente el servidor que debe dar la respuesta debe habilitar las requests que lleguen de un dominio o IP que no sean la suya, has verificado esta configuracion ?

Comment: @AngelFragaParodi El servidor lo tiene habilitado lo que creo que es algún problema que desconozco porque tengo una extensión de chrome "Cors" que si la activo no me salta el error.

Comment: Supongo que esta pregunta ya la habras resuelto hace mucho tiempo pero de todas maneras dejare este enlace acerca de las CORS, para aquellos proximos que vean esta pregunta, ya que no se marcar una respuesta externa de otra manera:

https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/278730/problema-con-cors-en-aplicaci%c3%b3n-laravel-con-frontend-angular/278774#278774