# Problema con cors en aplicación laravel con frontend Angular

Tags: laravel, angular, api, cors

Tengo un problema claro, tengo una api restful creada en laravel 5.2 y al hacer las peticiones con postman todo va perfectamente.

Sin embargo con mi aplicación angular no puedo acceder al servidor porque no tengo habilitado CORS:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8000/api/login' from origin 'http://localhost' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

He probado a instalar la librería de cors y me da fallo y a implementarlo de forma manual y nada. ¿es posible que haya algún error en la aplicación Angular?

Comment: Podrías mostrar el código de lo que has intentado?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pon la siguiente linea arriba del todo en el codigo.php donde intentas mandar información a algún archivo de angular:

```
<?php

     header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

?>
```

Por otro lado, no estoy completamente seguro, ya que esto que te voy a decir si es necesario en ionic, pero no se si en angular sólito como tal también, y es que siempre debes retornar algún valor así el valor que retornes sea undefined, o mas conocido como null en php, en tu caso, si quieres por ejemplo mandar la información como un JSON, puedes colocar adicionalmente esta linea despues de Access-Control-Allow-Origin:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset = UTF-8');
```

Y entonces retornas valores así:

```
$nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
$appelido = $_POST['apellido'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$resultado = json_encode(
     array(
           "nombre" => $nombre, 
           "apellido" => $apellido, 
           "contraseña" => $password
     )
);

echo $resultado;
```

Sin embargo no se nada de laravel, por lo que solo es que tu hagas lo mismo pero usando laravel despues de que hayas hecho los respectivos procesos a la data para que sea mas segura.

Lo otro que debes tener en cuenta, (Que a mi ya me paso) y fue un completo comedero de cabeza hasta que me di cuenta de la estupidez del error es que, si tu ya pusiste la linea:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

Y si aún así te sigue marcando el error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8000/api/login' from origin 'http://localhost' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

El error entonces ten por seguro que NO ES porque no encuentre la cabecera AccessControlAllowOrigin, si no que al hacer el request, si el programa encuentra que hay un error en tu código PHP, no se va a cargar el archivo.php y por lo tanto nunca va a encontrar la cabecera AccessControlAllowOrigin y te volvera a marcar el mismo error aunque ya hayas puesto la cabecera en el archivo.

**Solución sencilla:**

Debuguea tu código php y comprueba que todo funcione bien, si encuentras un error arreglalo y vuelve a intentarlo, puedes debuguear directamente el archivo abriendolo en localhost  y simulando el comportamiento del archivo con datos introducidos por ti en el mismisimo php, (De momento solo para debuguear que esta mal en el archivo).

Comment: Gracias, he añadido el header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); a los métodos login y register y ya me devuelven una respuesta sin bloquearse cors.

Comment: Oye por cierto las CORS, no son librerias dijiste que instalaste una libreria para ello, seguro es una libreria que sirve para alguna otra cosa, ya que las CORS no son instaladas, ellas vienen integradas en los navegadores por politicas de seguridad y por predeterminado lo que hacen es bloqueas peticiones HTTP, las CORS solo requieren ser habilitadas o deshabilitadas, no se requiere nada mas para trabajar con ellas :3

Comment: traté de utilizar la siguiente librería:https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors pero me daba un error, al final lo hice añadiendo CORS a cada método que hacía una petición externa y funcionó. Lo ideal sería hacerlo con un helper pero de momento era solo para un curso que me estaba dando problemas.